# How do I update all svn:externals references after a server migration?

Tags: svn, properties, migration, svn-externals, externals

I migrated an SVN server today and ran into an issue. I have a repo that has an svn:externals property on a trunk subfolder. This folder has been branched a bunch of times and now this svn:externals reference needs updated on every single branch to refer to the new server.

Is there an easy way to update all of these properties?

I'm not excited about updating them individually by hand.

I'm on windows, too, so a fancy [bash script](http://www.thomaskeller.biz/blog/2009/01/05/change-svnexternals-quickly/) won't work. There's got to be an easier way!

Note: this is from the old pre-1.5 days when svn:externals references had to be absolute.

---

Update: a simple `relocate` won't do it since these are absolute URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install Cygwin and use the bash script to which you linked.

Comment: I was hoping for something easier than that, thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Would a SVN Relocate work?

It's used when a repository has moved.

Comment: No, that moves my working folder, which is great, but doesn't update any properties. These are absolute urls to the old server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [SvnDumpTool](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/) for this.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204616/how-to-migrate-all-urls-in-svnexternals-properties-across-a-repository) other thread that has more discussion.