# Fixing up svn:externals properties in svnsync'd copy without new revisions?

Tags: svn, bash, svnsync

How can I fix the `svn:externals` property on existing revisions if I have admin rights on the local copy of an (`svnsync`'d) repository?

Let me demonstrate the idea with a script which would be named something like `fixup.sh` and placed inside the local repository root path (same folder that contains `conf/`, `db/`, `hooks/`, etc):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CURRBASENAME=$(dirname $(readlink -e $0))
svn propget -R svn:externals "file://$CURRBASENAME"|while read extrnls; do
    [[ -n "$extrnls" ]] || continue
    LOC=$(echo "$extrnls"|cut -f 1 -d ' ')
    NME=$(echo "$extrnls"|cut -f 3 -d ' ')
    REV=$(echo "$extrnls"|cut -f 4 -d ' ')
    [[ "${REV:0:2}" == "-r" ]] || REV=''
    [[ -z "$REV" ]] && EXT=$(echo "$extrnls"|cut -f 4 -d ' ')
    [[ -n "$REV" ]] && EXT=$(echo "$extrnls"|cut -f 5 -d ' ')
    LOCALIZED="^/${EXT##*/svn/}"

    svnmucc -n -m "Adjusting svn:externals $NAME to: $LOCALIZED $REV" propset svn:externals "$NME $REV $LOCALIZED" "$LOC"
done
```

Note that the script would not work with paths that contain spaces, unless escaped.

Unfortunately this kind of modification will create new revisions, which in turn will make it impossible to incrementally update the local repo from the original remote repo.

Preferably I would want to do this during the `sync` phase, e.g. by means of a hook. The "solution" presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204616/) is more of a crutch than a solution, as it means that I would have to rewrite the history every time after syncing, effectively having to keep two separate copies: one modified and one "pristine" (well, besides the minor `svnsync` fixups).

NB: I'm working on the repo, not on a working copy. Also note that `svn:externals` is *not* a revprop!