# How can I redirect svn urls to another domain?

Tags: svn, redirect, dns, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

background: DynDNS has now started to require a once a month logon to keep their free accounts active (previously you only had to renew your IP address once a month). I am sure sooner or later I will forget to do that and lose my account.

I use mysvn.dyndns.org for accessing my subversion repository on a server which can (as of now) also be reached by svn.mydomain.com. Unfortunately most projects also refer to externals which are also located at mysvn.dyndns.org and I don't really want to go through all projects (>100) and change the externals, because that would probably take several hours and is rather error prone.

Is there any way to configure Windows or the subversion / TortoiseSVN clients to redirect one domain to another?

e.g.:

https://mysvn.dyndns.org/svn/blablub

should be redirected to

https://svn.mydomain.com/svn/blablub

I know that I can add an entry to hosts to redirect to an IP address, but I would prefer redirection to a domain name.

Comment: what version of svn client and server?

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question, but can I suggest an alternate approach? Assuming you're using svn 1.5 or higher which supports [relative URLs for externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html), following one of the approaches [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204616/how-to-migrate-all-urls-in-svnexternals-properties-across-a-repository) to change all externals to relative would solve the more fundamental problem.

Comment: @explunit: That is an interesting approach. Unfortunately it won't work for all the projects since they are not all stored in the same repository as their externals. But the majority is. Please add this as an answer, you might get the bounty even if it does not answer the question as I put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no solution as easy as I thought it might be. I ended up writing a small Delphi program based on the Version Insight source code which changes the externals for all projects checked out into subdirectories of a given directory and committing these changes. Then I used the svn relocate command to relocate the projects themselves.

```
@rem calls svn relocate for all directories
@echo off

for /d %%i in (*) do call :HandleDir %%i
pause
goto :eof

:HandleDir
echo *** handling dir %1

svn relocate --ignore-externals https://mysvn.dyndns.org/svn/ https://svn.mydomain.com/svn/ %1
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 5):

You (really) asked 2 related questions:

- Can I redirect `somename.domain.com` to `anothername.somedomain.com`?
- Can SVN-clients use old name, but intecat with new host?

And short answers will be

- Yes
- No

**Longer versions**

For redirecting old hostname to new you have and can use at least two variations (with the same final result)

- At the DNS level and CNAME record, which will alias new name to new:

`somename.domain.com. IN CNAME anothername.somedomain.com`

on request of somename will answer with data from anothername

- In the Apache's config for host of location somename you can add redirect to anothername Apache's

**But**: it will work only on browsers's level - when you'll try to use this redirected location as target for any Subversion's command, you'll get error "Repository moved, please relocate" and you **must** relocate all old resources to new URL.

Good news for your

All externals definition are written as svn-properties inside source repo, you can get list of these externals (with values) and update with the new values, and this operation (theoretically) can be automated

`svn propget -R svn:externals . > FILE` in the root of working copy for getting externals

`svn propset svn:externals --target FILE` for defining new externals in batch

Comment: So for 1 I need access to a DNS for the domain dyndns.org? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @dummzeuch - no, you have to have access to zone `mydomain.com` in order to add into domains RRs `svn IN CNAME mysvn.dyndns.org`, but read p.2 after it - it will not solve problem of accessing svn-clients

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest an alternate approach?

Assuming you're using svn 1.5 or higher which [supports relative URLs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) for externals, following one of the approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204616/how-to-migrate-all-urls-in-svnexternals-properties-across-a-repository) to change all externals to relative would solve the more fundamental problem.

And if they are not all relative URLs, you can change them from server1 to server2 using a similar script. This is done routinely during server migrations. Assuming you keep good [backups](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup), it's probably the approach that will let you get all the pain resolved at one time rather than deferring it over time.